# c++ parse getline in dynamic array

Tags: c++, foreach, dynamic-arrays

I already asked, how I can parse single words from a stream into variables, and that works perfectly, but I don't know how many words the user will give as input. I thought I could parse it into a dynamic array, but I don't know where to start. How can I write "for each word in line"?

This is how I parse the words into the vars:

```
string line;
getline( cin, line );
istringstream parse( line );
string first, second, third;
parse >> first >> second >> third;
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to all of you, I think I get it know... and it works!

Comment: You can keep popping it out to a temp variable and pushing that onto a vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::list<std::string>` -- they handle the resizing automatically.

```
istringstream parse( line ); 
vector<string> v;
string data; 
while (parse >> data) {
  v.push_back(data);
}
```

Comment: Ok, i really like Alexander Bakulins answer, because I understand it right away, but I think there is a reason why you guys recommend vector and push_back. Could you explain it? I haven't worked with vector before

Comment: @mohrphium, A vector is a dynamic array that does the memory management for you.

Comment: @mohrphium - if you can process the element right away (so you don't need to store it) Alexander's answer works fine.  You were asking about storing the extracted values.  The STL collections are suggested over raw arrays as they handle the heavy lifing for you by doing the memory management (e.g. resizing) automatically and well.  You can even have bounds checking if you want (e.g. using the `at()` function); or just use iterators.  Since you are writing programs in C++, you should learn the features of the language -- especially the STL - it will make life much easier for you in the long run

Answer (score 5):

A possibility would be to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream in(std::string("a line from file"));

    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(words));

    return 0;
}
```

The `vector` will grow as required to store whatever number of words is provided by the user.

Comment: I understood Atilas answer, but I don't quite get the iterator stuff.. what does it do?

Comment: @mohrphium, if you click on the link in the answer it will give a full description.

Comment: @mohrphium perhaps start with [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator), it'll explain about what iterators are.

Answer (score 4):

You can write as follows:

```
string line;
getline( cin, line );
istringstream parse( line );
string word;
while (parse >> word)
    // do something with word
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with `foreach`, here's a way to do it with with standard `for_each` algorithm and C++11 lambdas:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for for_each
#include <vector>    // vector, obviously
#include <iterator>  // istream_iterator
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    vector<string> vec;
    getline(cin, line);

    istringstream parse(line);

    for_each(
        istream_iterator<string>(parse),
        istream_iterator<string>(),

        // third argument to for_each is a lambda function
        [](const string& str) {
             // do whatever you want with/to the string
             vec.push_back(str);  // push it to the vector
        }
    );
 }
```

A `vector` is exactly what you asked for - a dynamically resizable array that you should almost always prefer over C-style arrays. It's size need not to be known at compile time.